# Memory access after fork extremely slow on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, performance, fork

The following code executes about 200 times slower on Mac OS X than on Linux. I don't know why and the problem does **not** seem to be trivial. I suspect a bug in gcc on the Mac or in Mac OS X itself or in my hardware.

The code forks the process which will copy the page table entires but **not** the memory on Mac OS X. The memory is copied when written to which happens in the for loop at the end of the run method. There, for the first 4 calls of run, all pages have to be copied because every page is touched. For the second 4 calls to run where skip is 512, every second page needs to be copied since every second page is touched. Intuitively, the first 4 calls should take about twice as long as the second 4 calls which is absolutely not the case. For me, the output of the program is as follows:

```
169.655ms
670.559ms
2784.18ms
16007.1ms
16.207ms
25.018ms
42.712ms
79.676ms
```

On Linux it is

```
5.306ms
10.69ms
20.91ms
41.042ms
6.115ms
12.203ms
23.939ms
40.663ms
```

Total runtime on Mac OS X is rougly 20 seconds, about 0.5 seconds on Linux for the exact same program both times compiled with gcc. I've tried compiling the mac os version wiht gcc4, 4.2 and 4.4 - no change.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

class Timestamp
{
   private:
   timeval time;

   public:
   Timestamp() { gettimeofday(&time,0); }

   double operator-(const Timestamp& other) const { return static_cast<double>((static_cast<long long>(time.tv_sec)*1000000+(time.tv_usec))-(static_cast<long long>(other.time.tv_sec)*1000000+(other.time.tv_usec)))/1000.0; }
};

class ForkCoW
{
public:
   void run(uint64_t size, uint64_t skip) {
      // allocate and initialize array
      void* arrayVoid;
      posix_memalign(&arrayVoid, 4096, sizeof(uint64_t)*size);
      uint64_t* array = static_cast<uint64_t*>(arrayVoid);
      for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
         array[i] = 0;

      pid_t p = fork();
      if (p == 0)
         sleep(99999999);

      if (p < 0) {
         cerr << "ERRROR: Fork failed." << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }

      {
         Timestamp start;
         for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i += skip) {
            array[i] = 1;
         }
         Timestamp stop;
         cout << (stop-start) << "ms" << endl;
      }
      kill(p,SIGTERM);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   ForkCoW f;
   f.run(1ull*1000*1000, 512);
   f.run(2ull*1000*1000, 512);
   f.run(4ull*1000*1000, 512);
   f.run(8ull*1000*1000, 512);

   f.run(1ull*1000*1000, 513);
   f.run(2ull*1000*1000, 513);
   f.run(4ull*1000*1000, 513);
   f.run(8ull*1000*1000, 513);
}
```

Comment: Which of the two processes takes forever?

Comment: Have you profiled or stepped through the debugger or even put print statements to see where it's taking its time?

Comment: @goreSplatter: The parent of course. The child just has to hang around. I want to test CoW performance.

Comment: @Falmarri: The loop over the array takes _long_. It takes quadratically longer if you increase size (!!).

Comment: Funny, I've just tried it and the execution time on Mac OS is proportional to the length of the sleep.  If I sleep for 30 seconds it takes about 40 seconds total, and if I sleep for 20 seconds it takes about 25 seconds total.

Comment: @Paul This could be because of the computer running out of physical memory - see my answer: when the `sleep` ends, 400MB of memory are freed, allowing the remaining process to use physical memory.

Comment: OK not runtime, time output to standard out using the timestamps. Also note my remark on how I have >> memory than 2x 400 MB.

Comment: Also - for arguments sake - I've just run it and checked the swap counters - no swapping whatsoever. My swapfile was not used and is 1MB big.

Comment: It *is* the sleep command.  Your "proof by repeated assertion" is not proving anything.

Comment: I've rewritten my post to account for all your "solutions".

Comment: @Henrik Did you try my suggestion (Edit), first perform a write to array[0] to trigger the `write` then start the *timestamp*? This - if it shows that the time is back to normal - would identify the problem as being the memory allocation, not the loop that follows.

Comment: The second 4 calls touch pretty much every page, too. I think they'll skip 1 page every 512. The stride should be 1024 if you want to touch every other page. I don't think this makes the figures any clearer though. Perhaps OS X just doesn't want you to do anything except exec, after doing the fork? That's what the man page pretty much tells you to do, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Only reason for such a long sleep would be this line:

```
sleep(300000);
```

which results in 300 seconds of sleep (300*1000). Maybe the implementation of `fork()` is different on mac os x than you expect (and it always returns 0).

Comment: fork returns 0 to the child and a pid to the parent.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The code is sound, anything put right after the fork command and before the last loop is executed without a waiting period. Only the array access is slow.

Comment: Of course it returns 0 to the child; that's exactly the behavior I am looking for. The parent is supposed to change pages after the fork to trigger copy on write. The child just has to "hang around" to cause that effect.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with C++.  I rewrote your example in C and using waitpid(2) instead of sleep/SIGCHLD and cannot reproduce a problem:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void ForkCoWRun(uint64_t size, uint64_t skip) {
      // allocate and initialize array
      uint64_t* array;
      posix_memalign((void **)&array, 4096, sizeof(uint64_t)*size);
      for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
             array[i] = 0;

      pid_t p = fork();
      switch(p) {
          case -1:
              fprintf(stderr, "ERRROR: Fork failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          case 0:
          {
              struct timeval start, stop;
              gettimeofday(&start, 0);
              for (uint64_t i = 0; i < size; i += skip) {
                 array[i] = 1;
              }
              gettimeofday(&stop, 0);

              long microsecs = (long)(stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) *1000000 + (long)(stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
              printf("%ld.%03ld ms\n", microsecs / 1000, microsecs % 1000);
              exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
          }
          default:
          {
              int exit_status;
              waitpid(p, &exit_status, 0);
              break;
          }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ForkCoWRun(1ull*1000*1000, 512);
    ForkCoWRun(2ull*1000*1000, 512);
    ForkCoWRun(4ull*1000*1000, 512);
    ForkCoWRun(8ull*1000*1000, 512);

    ForkCoWRun(1ull*1000*1000, 513);
    ForkCoWRun(2ull*1000*1000, 513);
    ForkCoWRun(4ull*1000*1000, 513);
    ForkCoWRun(8ull*1000*1000, 513);
}
```

and on OS X 10.8, 10.9, and 10.10, I get results like:

```
6.163 ms
12.239 ms
24.529 ms
49.223 ms
6.027 ms
12.081 ms
24.270 ms
49.498 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the order of execution on Linux is that it runs the parent first, and then the parent executes and the child terminates because its parent is gone, but on Mac OS it runs the child first, which involves a 300 second sleep.

There is *absolutely* no guarantee in any Unix standard that the two processes after a fork will run in parallel.  Your assertions about the capability of the OS to do so notwithstanding.

Just to prove it's the sleep time, I replaced the "30000" your code with "SLEEPTIME" and compiled and ran it with `g++ -DSLEEPTIME=?? foo.c && ./a.out`:

```
SLEEPTIME   output
20          20442.1
30          30468.5
40          40431.4
10          10449  <just to prove it wasn't getting longer each run>
```

Comment: a) they run in parallel 
b) if you decrease size the process still takes a long time (100 times longer than on linux) but much less than 300 seconds so no, that's not the reason.

Comment: I just tried it 3 times with different sleep lengths but no other changes, and the run time is directly proportional to the sleep times.  And who told you that forked processes run in parallel?  There is no guarantee of that in the standard - if you want parallel execution, use pthreads.

Comment: Scratch the word runtime. The timestamp difference being output to standard out from the parent is much much lower on linux (multiple orders of magnitude). You have 2 processes after the fork. You have an operating system with multitasking. Both tasks have the same priorities. I have multiple cores. How on earth or the two processes supposed to not run in parallel?

Comment: Show me the documentation that says that after a fork, the two processes run in parallel?

Comment: @Paul: There is nothing saying they will be run in parallel. **BUT** The fork should create a *new* processes (that is what fork does). On a `preemptive multiprocessing OS` (Like Unix) all user processes should get approximately equal time being scheduled for execution. The child processes uses sleep() which does give up the CPU time slot the current processes is using allowing another processes to get another slot. That does not mean the parent gets the next available slot though, but the parent should get some slots in while the child sleeps.

Comment: Btw. I just need to point out that linux is a system that allows two processes to run in parallel. When you fork, two processes are created and they are scheduled separately. A sane implementation will not let one process wait until the other one terminates; this would avoid all race conditions - which is awesome - but also sequentialize a multithreaded multiuser system - which is less awesome. Henrik

Comment: @Paul: fork() guarantees that the processes will run in parallel given the required system resources. A fork() literally creates a new thread, but inside a new process. Why would it not be "guaranteed" to run in parallel?

Comment: @Henrik: No processes need not be run in parallel at all even in sane implementation. Though by interleaving the processing using slots the appearance of parallelism is achieved.

Comment: @York Be that as it may - that's good enough in my case. Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating 400 megabytes once, and once again from the `fork()` (Since the process is duplicated including the memory allocation).

The reason of the slowness could be simply that from the `fork()` with two processes, you run out of available physical memory, and are using the `swap` memory from the disk.

This is usually much slower than using the physical memory.

**Edit** following comments

I suggest you change the code to start the timing measurement after writing to the first element of the array.

```
  array[0] = 1;
  Timestamp start;
    for (int64_t i = 1; i < size; i++) {
       array[i] = 1;
```

This way, the time used by the memory allocation following the first write will not be taken into account in the *timestamp*.

Comment: I thought modern `fork` is "copy on write" just like BSD `vfork`.

Comment: Oh, but he does write to them, so yeah, it would have to make a copy.  Never mind.

Comment: I have 8 gigs of memory 6 of which are free. fork uses copy on write. There's not swapping involved.

Comment: Exactly, the `write` starts when the first item of the array is stored. The array being big (400MB) the allocation + copy may take some time (then assignment to 1). The main culprit is likely to be the allocation. Please see my edit.

Comment: Because the allocation is not performed the same way - this is just an assumption, but memory allocation uses various algorithms, more or less well performing depending on various factors, like the size of the segment.

Comment: Please see my edit of the original question. The allocation done when writing to the array after the fork is supposed to be slower but not by two orders of magnitude.

Comment: I'll grant that memory allocation uses different procedures on each, but they both (AFAIK) use copy-on-write pages, and if Mac OS X had to swap to disk to get 400 MB of writable memory (which he says the OS reports that it's not doing), I don't know what approach Linux could do to get around this.  If you don't have 400 MB of RAM physically available, the world's cleverest malloc algorithm isn't going to give you performance as if you did.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you have the parent `waitpid()` on the child and ensure that it is exited (and to be safe handle `SIGCHLD` to ensure that the process is reaped.)  It seems possible that on Linux the child could have exited sooner and now the page fault handler has to do less work to copy-on-write since the pages are only referenced by a single process.

Second...  Do you have any idea the kind of work `fork()` has to do?  In particular it should not be assumed to be "fast".  Semantically speaking, it has to duplicate every page in the process's address space.  Historically this is what old Unix did, so they say.  This is improved by initially marking these pages as "copy-on-write" (that is, the pages are marked read-only and the kernel's page fault handler will duplicate them at the first write), but this is *still* a lot of work, and it means that your first write access on every page will be slow.

I congratulate the Linux developers for getting their `fork()` and their copy-on-write implementation very fast for your access pattern...  But it seems a very strange thing to claim that it's a huge problem if Mac OS's kernel is not as good, or if other parts of the system happen to generate different access patterns, or whatever.  Fork, and writing pages after a fork, is not *supposed* to be fast.

I suppose what I am trying to say is if you move your code to a kernel that has a different set of design choices and all of a sudden your `fork()`s are slower, tough, that's part of moving your code to a different OS.

Comment: Hi. This post is decently researched but sadly I am not complaining about the fork performance but about the copy on write performance. Copy on write on the mac for this particular case is about 200 timmes slower (that's two orders of magnitude!) than _reallocating fresh memory and writing to it. Please also note that I've updated and clarified the question.

Answer (score -1):

Have you verified that fork() is working:

```
int main() 
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if( pid > 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Parent\n";
    } else if( pid == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "Child\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to fork!\n";
    }
}
```

Maybe there is some restriction on MAC OS-X about forking child processes.